# Fast way to get information from a huge logfile on unix

Tags: text-processing, grep

I have a 6 GB application log file. The loglines have the following format (shortened)

```
[...]
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-ABC;type=m
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-ABC;set_to_TRUE
[...]
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-HHH;type=m
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-HHH;set_to_FALSE
[...]
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-ZZZ;type=m
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-ZZZ;set_to_FALSE
[...]
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-WWW;type=s
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-WWW;set_to_TRUE
```

I have a lot of session with more then these 2 lines.
I need to find out all sessions with `type=m` and `set_to_TRUE`

My first attempt was to grep all sessionIDs with `type=m` and write it into a file. Then looping with every line from the file (1 sessionID per line) trough the big logfile and grep for `sessionID;set_to_TRUE`

This method takes a loooot of time. Can anyone give me a hint to solve this in a much better and faster way?

Comment: Do you just want the session names or all lines pertaining to those sessions? In the latter case: is there any way to know when no more lines will appear for a session? And do you know that "type" will appear before "set_to_(TRUE|FALSE)"?

Comment: in short words: i need to count all type=m, which were set to TRUE or FALSE.

in case these information are spread over 2 different lines, i only have the session-ID to get the information connected.

Comment: I figured that out from you sample data, but that doesn't answer what you need the output to be, or whether you know if the order will be as shown.

Comment: As a general rule you should always post a relevant input sample. You've already got two answers that assume those lines are consecutive... which is not the case.

Comment: @xMaNuu Here you say you want all type=m which are set to TRUE or FALSE, whereas in your question you write that type=m and set to TRUE. Which of these is the actual spec?

Comment: @xMaNuu Also are the `[...]` actual lines or just a representation meaning continuation lines? Can you post a realistic data sample

Comment: `You really need to give a few lines of a realistic data input or you will only get answers fitting to the sample you give.

Answer (score 1):

If each session has a corresponding `type` and is `set_to` either `TRUE` or `FALSE` then you could use `sed` and ranges to do it:

```
sed '/type=m/,/set_to_/!d;/set_to_TRUE$/!d;s/.*\(sessionid-.*\);.*/\1/' infile
```

This removes all lines that are not in the `/type=m/,/set_to_/` ranges. It also deletes the lines in those ranges that don't end in `set_to_TRUE`. The `sessionid` is then extracted from the remaining line (if any).
Alternatively,

```
sed -n '/type=/h;/set_to_TRUE$/{
x;s/.*\(sessionid-.*\);type=m$/\1/p
}' infile
```

should print the same.
The latter works by overwriting the hold buffer on each line matching `type=`
Then, on each line matching `set_to_TRUE`, the buffers are exchanged and a substitution is attempted - namely, extract `sessionid` from a line ending in `type=m` - and if successful, the result is `p`rinted. Otherwise, nothing happens since autoprinting is disabled via `-n`.
The above assumes there are no trailing blanks on your lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F";" '/type=m/{flag=$3;next} /set_to_TRUE/ && ($3==flag)' infile.txt
```

it will match if both sessionIDs were same and required conditions also seen.

```
timestamp;hostname;sessionid-ABC;set_to_TRUE
```

above will print entire line, you can print only desired column by adding `print $3` in order to have only sessionIDs, like below:

```
awk -F";" '/type=m/{flag=$3;next} /set_to_TRUE/ && ($3==flag){print $3}' infile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using grep it can be done pretty easy:

```
grep -E "(type=|set_to_)" file.txt | grep -A 1 "type=m" | grep -B 1 "set_to_TRUE" > file1.txt &
```

Put it in the background get a coffee and let it finish. Not sure if 'awk' nor 'sed' would be quicker. 6GB are alot for only text, that's why it will take a long time anyway you try to do it.

You'd see when it is finished in the console anyway once you press enter or type in another command as:

```
[1]+  Done                    grep --color=auto -E '(type=|set_to_)' file.txt | grep --color=auto -A 1 "type=m" | grep --color=auto -B 1 "set_to_TRUE" > file1.txt
```

Comment: @don_crissti Hmm, why doesn't he edit his question then? Does this mean there can be more then one session opened aswell? So there can be two type=m and afterwards 2 sessions_set_to some time later? That's kinda not clear from his example given.

Comment: I adjusted it so it fits the only one session at a time.

Comment: When it comes to searching, `grep` is faster than `sed` and `awk` (it's optimized for search). In this particular case (OP is looking for fixed strings, not regex) you can make it even faster using the `-F` switch with all three `grep` invocations. However, how much faster this could be depends on the number of matches (if 80% of the lines contained `type=` or `set_to` then you could say you're almost processing the file twice etc). Then there's the problem of `sessionid`. If the OP needs only that information (not the entire lines) you'll have to do some post-processing.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- you only want the session names
- the "type=" line will come before the "set_to_" line
- you actually meant that you only want sessions where "set_to_TRUE", as written in the question (which you contradicted in a comment)

If you need to handle multiple open sessions at once (it's not clear), you can do something like (untested):

```
perl -ne 'if (m/<timestamp>;<hostname>;(sessionid-[a-z]+);type=(.)/) { $type{$1}=$2 }; if (m/<timestamp>;<hostname>;(sessionid-[a-z]+);set_to_TRUE/) { if ($type{$1} eq "m") { print $1 } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F';' '/type=m/ { seen[$3]=1 };
           /set_to_TRUE/ && seen[$3] { print $3 ; delete seen[$3] };
           /set_to_FALSE/ && seen[$3] { delete seen[$3] }' logfile.txt
```

This is similar to [αғsнιη's answer](/a/382352/72456), but instead of using just a single variable (`flag`), it uses an array (`seen`) to keep track of which session-ids it has seen that match `type=m`.

This means that it works even when there are other `type=m` lines for different sessions between the sighting of any session's `type=m` line and sighting that session's `set_to_` line.

To minimise memory requirements for the script, it deletes the `seen` array element for a given session-id as soon as it sees either a matching `set_to_TRUE` or `set_to_FALSE`.

NOTE: The script above prints only the matching session-ids.  If you want to print the actual `type=m` and `set_to_TRUE` lines, the awk script would be:

```
awk -F';' '/type=m/ { seen[$3]=$0 };
           /set_to_TRUE/ && seen[$3] { print seen[$3]"\n"$0 ; delete seen[$3] };
           /set_to_FALSE/ && seen[$3] { delete seen[$3] }' logfile.txt
```

This has the potential to use a LOT more memory.  Storing entire input lines in an array takes a lot more RAM than storing integers.

NOTE2: this script assumes the session-ids are unique.  If, for example, it is possible that different hostnames (field 2) may generate the same session-id, try this instead:

```
awk -F';' '/type=m/ { seen[$3$2]=1 };
           /set_to_TRUE/ && seen[$3$2] { print $3 ; delete seen[$3$2] };
           /set_to_FALSE/ && seen[$3$2] { delete seen[$3$2] }' logfile.txt
```

or

```
awk -F';' '/type=m/ { seen[$3$2]=$0 };
           /set_to_TRUE/ && seen[$3$2] {print seen[$3$2]"\n"$0;delete seen[$3$2]};
           /set_to_FALSE/ && seen[$3$2] { delete seen[$3$2] }' logfile.txt
```